# How to handle issue with some rows in csv files for pipefittings in revit api?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am facing a weird issue in Revit API c# while working with pipefittings and CSV files. The base model I am working on is a pipefitting where I need to upload a CSV file.

```
FamilySizeTableManager TableManager = FamilySizeTableManager.GetFamilySizeTableManager(famDoc, famDoc.OwnerFamily.Id);
if (TableManager.IsValidObject)
{
     using (Transaction trans = new Transaction(famDoc))
     {
         trans.Start("import lookup table");
         FamilySizeTableErrorInfo errorInfo = new FamilySizeTableErrorInfo();
         result = TableManager.ImportSizeTable(famDoc, csvPath, errorInfo);
         trans.Commit();
     }
}
```

I added the CSV file name as follows, where `tableDimensions` is the name of the CSV file:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tableDimensions))
{
     Parameters.SetParameterFamily(famManager, famDoc, "DATA", ParameterType.Text, false, "TABLE_DIMENSIONS", tableDimensions);
}
```

This CSV file contains 15-20 rows. Up to 10 rows, it works properly, but on the 11 rows I get the error as:

1. Line is too short.
2. Can't create the surface of revolution

The weird part is that, when I do this task manually from the Revit UI, it works properly.

So the CSV format seems to be correct, because 10 rows are executing correctly, and the value on this particular row is correct because it works properly on trying it manually via Revit UI.

Did someone face a similar issue that works manually but not programmatically? Also is there a better way to handle this issue or get more details to pinpoint this issue?

**Edit:**
small extract of the csv

;DN##LENGTH##MILLIMETERS;PN##LENGTH##MILLIMETERS;LMX##LENGTH##MILLIMETERS;DE##LENGTH##MILLIMETERS;M_THICKNESS##LENGTH##MILLIMETERS;I_COAT_THICKNESS##LENGTH##MILLIMETERS;E_COAT_THICKNESS##LENGTH##MILLIMETERS;MASS##MASS##KILOGRAMS;P_THICKNESS##LENGTH##MILLIMETERS;P_SIZE##LENGTH##MILLIMETERS
BBA1;60;10;500;90;6.0;4.0;0;11;16.0;175
BBA2;80;10;500;98;6.0;4.0;0;15;16.0;200
BBA3;100;10;500;118;6.0;4.0;0;18;16.0;220
BBA4;125;10;500;144;6.0;4.0;0;22;16.0;250
BBA5;600;10;550;635;9.9;5.0;0;220;26.0;780
The last row fails but works in Revit UI.

Comment: would you mind adding 4 or 5 correct rows and the faulty row?

Comment: Hello @Marco, thanks for your reply, I have edited the question and added the rows

Comment: Why is there a leading semi-colon in your heading row? This looks odd.

Comment: That is a blank title for the values "BBA1, BBA2, BBA3.."

Comment: The error suggests, that a value is too small to be added. This should have nothing to do with a line or row of data, but an actual dimension of length based on a numerical value.

Comment: yes, that is right, the problem is that it works when I do manually, but the only the last row fails when tested via code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236801/discussion-between-jpais-and-marco).